# Multiple primitives with different color for one Mesh object (glTF 2)

Tags: gltf

I am leveraging mesh with multiple primitives to support a cube with different face colors. I found two possible implementations:

1. Duplicate the shared vertex.

From the example https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Asset-Generator/tree/master/Output/Positive/Mesh_Primitives it duplicate the vertex for shared vertex in order to create separate buffer view and vertex accessors. My understanding is this way will increase the file size as duplicate data write out but may have better drawing performance as it only load suset of data in each gl draw.

2. share the buffer view and vertex accessor for all primitives

Alternatively we can avoid the vertex duplication by writing all vertexes into the buffer and create single buffer view (hence vertex accessor) for different faces, as a result each primitive actually linked to the whole vertexes in the buffer. the impacts I guess is each primitive will have load all vertex in the buffer and this may lead drawing performance not good?

I would like to hear which manner is recommended? Thank you!

Comment: This is probably a subjective question, depending on what you want to do — it looks like there are some suggestions in the glTF Slack here?

Comment: Yes. I got some feedback from glTF slack. Will close this one.